# How do I create a macro that copies one row down based on the # of records in another sheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, vba

Using Access I export/create a daily Excel spreadsheet which has an increasing number of records/rows.

I'd like to then open a master Excel sheet, which:

1. Opens the exported sheet.
2. Counts the number of rows in the exported sheet which have data, then
3. Copies a particular row in the master sheet, down the same number of rows that there are records in the exported sheet, plus 1.

I used to do this in Lotus, but Windows 7 won't work with 1-2-3, and the macros won't convert.

Answer (score 3):

Use VBA.

First, open the other workbook.

Second, get the count like this:

```
ExportRows = Workbooks("Other").Sheets("Export").UsedRange.Rows.Count
```

Third, copy the row

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(ExportRows+1).Copy
```

Then you can paste it where you want.